# Powershell Script runs but nothing happens

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, handbrake

I'm trying to get this script to do a subdirectory compare based on filename and then only files that are 30 days or younger. The Syntax seems to acceptable but the HandbrakeCLI encoding doesn't launch.

```
    Clear screen
    $SourceDir = "\\netshare\testing\Source\*.MP4"
    $DestinationDir = "\\netshare\testing\Completed_mp4\*.MP4"
    $s1 = get-childitem -path $SourceDir -Recurse -Force | Where-Object        {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).addDays(-30)}
    $d1 = get-childitem -path $DestinationDir -Recurse
    $results = @(compare-object $s1 $d1) | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $_.Name}
    $quantity = $results | measure
    $Filecount = $quantity

    $Process = 0;
    foreach ($result in $results){

    Write-Host -----------------------------------------------------------------    
    Write-Host Handbrake Batch Encoding
$Process++;
$results = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + ".MP4";

$progress = ($Process / $filecount) * 100
    $progress = [Math]::Round($progress,2)

    #Clear-Host
    Write-Host "Processing - $results"
    Write-Host "File $Process of $Filecount - $progress%"
    Write-Host -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$s1 = get-childitem -path $SourceDir -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).addDays(-30)}
$d1 = get-childitem -path $DestinationDir -Recurse
Start-Process "C:\Users\Downloads\HandBrakeCLI-1.0.1-win-x86_64.exe -ArgumentList -q 25 -i '$results' -o '$d1'"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$results = @(compare-object $s1 $d1) | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $_.Name}
```

would be a good start to look. This will not return any results unless `$_.Name` is `NaN` (which is unlikely).

Once you fixed that there should be an error message that

```
C:\Users\Downloads\HandBrakeCLI-1.0.1-win-x86_64.exe -ArgumentList -q 25 -i '$results' -o '$d1'
```

cannot be run.

Note that you use quotation marks around the whole line, effectively telling `Start-Process` that the whole thing is the program to run. Which it isn't.

There's no need for `Start-Process` here anyway, though, you should be able to just use

```
C:\Users\Downloads\HandBrakeCLI-1.0.1-win-x86_64.exe -q 25 -i $results -o $d1
```

(Note also that due to your use of single quotes, you were passing `$results` and `$d1` verbatim to the program instead of the variable contents. Furthermore I'm fairly sure you'd need commas between arguments with `-ArgumentList` instead of spaces, as that would be normal PowerShell parameter binding behaviour.)

There are a bunch of other mistakes here:

1. `Clear screen` can just be `clear`, `cls`, or `Clear-Host`. The `screen` does nothing.
2. `$quantity = $results | measure` should probably be `$quantity = ($results | measure).Count` or simply `@($results).Count`. Otherwise you won't get the output you want a few lines later.

Comment: Thank You so very much Joey.

Comment: It seems the for each object loop isn't populating the $results variable.

Comment: How do I re-write   $results = @(compare-object $s1 $d1) | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $_.Name}  So it compares filenames of both directories and ingnores matches. Only passings non-matching file names to handbrake?